# Error “Element script must not have attribute defer unless attribute src is also specified” from W3C validator

Tags: javascript, html, w3c-validation, deferred-loading

I have an HTML document whose source has a `script` element that has a `defer` attribute. The W3C validator says it isn't valid because it lacks the `src` attribute, but in fact there is a `src` attribute is in the source:

```
<script defer type="text/javascript">if($(window).width()>1024){document.write("<"+"script src='js/jquery.preloader.js'></"+"script>");}</script>
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker (validator) here.

The fix: put the script contents into a separate file and use the `src` attribute to reference that.

The checker reports an error for the snippet in the question because the HTML spec used to explicitly state that the `script` can’t have a `defer` attribute unless it also has a `src` attribute.

The spec no longer explicitly states that restriction, but I think that’s just an [unintentional regression caused by a later spec change](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/cd1a9fb1e83f7d0bc30be8b34ecdaf444a0b19a4#diff-36cd38f49b9afa08222c0dc9ebfe35ebL59339) (which your question helped to catch—so, thanks!).

So I’ll investigate and raise a pull request for the spec fix and then update this answer later.

**2018-05-05 update**

For the record here, I did end up filing a pull request with an HTML spec patch:

https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/2509

…and that was merged into the HTML spec source:

https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/3c5180a08f90a375c64f8191f32f8c7ddfec0ba3

…and so now the current HTML spec once again states the restriction:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-defer

> The `async` and `defer` attributes are boolean attributes that indicate how the script should be evaluated. Classic scripts may specify `defer` or `async`, but must not specify either unless the `src` attribute is present.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `<script>` tags.

- One which is in the HTML source
- One which is generated using `document.write`.

The HTML one looks like this:

```
<script defer type="text/javascript">…</script>
```

It has no `src` attribute. That is why you get the error. You can't have a `defer` attribute there.

The one generated by JavaScript looks like this:

```
if ($(window).width()>1024){
    document.write("<"+"script src='js/jquery.preloader.js'></"+"script>");
}
```

It has a `src` attribute and doesn't have a `defer` attribute. You could add a `defer` attribute here.

It is also JavaScript so won't be treated as HTML by the validator anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set your DOCTYPE to HTML5. If not feasable, you'll probably need to write `defer=true` instead of `defer`.

Comment: Defer=true gives a bad value error. And I already have the HTML doctype for html5